# Unable to run sudo commands

Tags: 18.04

Everytime I try to run an installation or root command in my Ubuntu I get this error. Can someone help me with fixes? How can I run it?
Searching this on the google I got no results.

This is the error:
[image: This is error]

Another kind of error:
[image: Not able to run this also]

Comment: THat's not a sudo error, that's a package installation error. As `apt` informs you, something's broken in your installation. In particular, you have installed a newer version of `libglapi-mesa` than expected by `libglx-mesa0` (you probably need to update the latter?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the answer to you question is however, it probably isn't a lack of ability to use the sudo command.  I've since instances where root is denied access to a file/folder.  So what's the proof with regard to sudo?  Try to do something routine that only root can do.  Everyone can do "ls" on almost every directory in the system but only root can see what's in the directory /root so, try the command sudo ls -l /root

If that works, your problem isn't ability to use root (ie. sudo).

Comment: It shows `total 0` when I run `sudo ls -l /root`. But why I am getting that error(as in image). Can you help in that respect?

Comment: I've seen root denied but can't remember what it was. /root was a try at testing your authorization for sudo but unfortunately, /root could easily be an empty folder.  Try sudo ls with some other folder that you don't normally have access to or perhaps use the cat command to see a file you don't normally have authority to view.  This is all to 'eliminate sudo from you inquiries' as you seek to answer the bigger question of how to fix your issues with apt